# Can I move Windows 7 to a larger partition with 'dd' instead of WinClone?

Tags: bootcamp, partition, windows

I have a Modbook Pro with both Win 7 and OS X installed during build; no media provided.  I got fed up with all the irritations of the modbook and bought a regular Macbook Pro with a larger drive and OS X only.

If I create a bootcamp partition that is larger than the previous Windows, and copy the old partition via 'dd,' I will have a partition the same size as before with the remainder 'free space.'  Can I then stretch that partition with Disk Utility to get back the size I want?

Comment: The edit you've submitted  to my answer was rejected as it belongs either as part of your OP or a comment, not part of the answer I've provided.

Answer (score 2):

While you could technically use `dd` to image a smaller partition onto a larger partition and it still show using the space of the smaller partition you'll not be able to resize the NTFS partition using Disk Utility.  Also the GPT and PMBR will not be synced and that will need to be resolved. Windows 7 will also need to be reactivated.

That said, using Winclone (at least Standard version) would be a much better option as it will handle what's necessary that Disk Utility can't, except for reactivating Windows, which is totally a Microsoft issue in resolution.

Comment: So an exact copy will not be activated?  Then it isn't really an exact copy?  Or the key encrypts some info about the hardware?  Hmmm.  If I boot Windows and somehow get it activated, I can resize from Windows?

Comment: @WGroleau, If you create the image on the Modbook and apply it to the MacBook Pro then while the initial contents of the image itself would be the same using `dd` nonetheless Windows is going see different hardware when the newly imaged partition is booted.  Winclone is going to be the same from a reactivation standpoint, it just makes the whole process easier then `dd`, sans the reactivation issue.

Comment: @WGroleau, I see you have unchecked this as the correct answer, care to offer a reason for doing so? Is it because your edit to my answer was rejected?

Comment: The answer seemed incomplete without that.  Petulance is not a factor.

Comment: @WGroleau, My answer as it stands is a correct answer and you had marked it so, whether or not you want to acknowledge it now!  Had you phrased your edit differently maybe it  wouldn't have been rejected. As it was you should have added it as a comment, then maybe I would have incorporated something about licensing it into my answer. The onus to use a particular type of license is on the User and individual Users are not allowed to use most OEM versions unless preinstalled by the OEM. There are exceptions however your question/situation was a technical one and not necessarily about licensing.